# Executing async code after startup, once API is up for requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to execute logic on start up of my web API and this code will also be async.

I've thought of `IStartupFilter` but this is sync, which is a problem. `StartUp.Configure()` is also not an option, sync.

I've thought of `IHostedService` but this runs before the application is done loading and up for requests.

Any other ways of doing this ?

Comment: What's the nature of what you want to execute? Is it something you need to run once, a long-lived process, or...?

Comment: Everytime the api starts. Not particularly long running.

Comment: One option is https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-part-1/#4-manually-running-tasks-in-program-cs

Answer (score 4):

Something you probably didn't realize is that running the application has 2 parts, that are hidden by default when you call `IHost.Run`/`IHost.RunAsync`.

Basically, this:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

await host.StartAsync();
await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
```

When `StartAsync` returns, the application has already started and is ready to consume requests, so you probably want to do this:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

await host.StartAsync();

await PerformSomeWorkAfterStartupAsync();

await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
```

Comment: Very useful. Is there a way to register a service/middleware/etc so it runs right where `PerformSomeWorkAfterStartupAsync()` is without having a dev. edit that specific part ?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Not that I know of, this was the best I could find after quite an extensive search, as I needed something similar some months ago

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IStartupTask`, register `StartupTaskRunner` and  `YourStartupTask` in DI:

```
services    
    .AddStartupTasksRunner()
    .AddStartupTask<YourStartupTask>();
```

And here the code based on [Andrew's Lock](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/) post:

```
public interface IAsyncStartupTask
{
    Task OnStartupAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

```
internal class StartupTasksRunner : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IAsyncStartupTask> _startupTasks;

    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public StartupTasksRunner(IEnumerable<IAsyncStartupTask> startupTasks, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        _startupTasks = startupTasks;
        _applicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;

        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => _semaphore.Release());
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // wait for ApplicationStarted event to execute when app is listening to web requests
        // await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

        foreach (var task in _startupTasks)
        {
            try
            {
                await task.OnStartupAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch
            {
                // stop the application if failing startup task if fatal
                //_applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddStartupTasksRunner(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddHostedService<StartupTasksRunner>();
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddStartupTask<TStartupTask>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where TStartupTask : class, IAsyncStartupTask
    {
        return services.AddSingleton<IAsyncStartupTask, TStartupTask>();
    }
}
```

**Notes**
The app [startup order](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.11/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/WebHost.cs#L153-L163) is:

1. Start `HostedService`'s
2. Start Kesterl Server
3. Fire `ApplicationStarted` event

If you want to run your startup task **before `HostedService`s started** you need to make sure `StartupTasksRunner` registered before any other `HostedService` (they are started in registration order).

If you want to run your startup task **after all `HostedService`s started** but **before application starts to receive web requests** make sure you are registering `StartupTasksRunner` after any other `HostedService`.

If you want to run your startup task **after Kestrel Server is started** uncomment `// await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);` line. Be aware that it may run concurrently with web requests handling.

Also be aware that exceptions thrown by `IHostedService.StartAsync` method will be [swallowed](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostedServiceExecutor.cs#L32) by framework. So if successful execution of startup tasks is necessary for your application uncomment `// _applicationLifetime.StopApplication();`

Comment: This is executing before the application is ready

Comment: @FrancisDucharme see my updated answer.