AddSingleton and AddHostedService in WebAPI application
In my application I have some services to manage some devices on a PC (mainly via serial ports). Services will be accessed through API controllers.
Each service must run as singleton (single instance) as they will use a serial port each.
Currently I'm using TInterface:TImplementationClass pattern , to take advantage of DI/IoC framework, and to be able to write mock methods to test various functionalities.
I have a DeviceManagerService that is the implementation class declared as follow:
DeviceManagerService : IDeviceManagerService
and IDeviceManagerService is the service interface declared as follow:
IDeviceManagerService : IHostedService
I'm using IHostedService interface to be able to do some startup configuration in StartAsync method, as if I don't register it as HostedService, no method is launched at startup, but only the constructor is called when first accessing the service.
then in my API controller I have
SerialPortController(ILogger<SerialPortController> logger, IDeviceManagerService devicesManager)
so I'm able to call various methods of the service from the controller itself
I've tried registering my service like this:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDeviceManagerService, DeviceManagerService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DeviceManagerService>());

but I'm getting
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'APIServer.HostedServices.DeviceManagerService' has been registered.'
Also registering like this:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DeviceManagerService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<IDeviceManagerService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DeviceManagerService>());

throws an 'Unable to resolve service for type IDeviceManagerService' exception when calling IDeviceManagerService from API controller.
Lastly I tried also doing this:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDeviceManagerService, DeviceManagerService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<DeviceManagerService>();

but two instances of DeviceManagerService are created, and StartAsync is called only once.
The only working method I found is this:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DeviceManagerService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDeviceManagerService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DeviceManagerService>());
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DeviceManagerService>());

What is the purpose of AddHostedService if it doesn't register the Interface?
And why do I have to call AddSingleton separately once for the implementation class and once for the Interface?
Should this builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDeviceManagerService, DeviceManagerService>(); be sufficient to register the Interface and Implementation type and then using AddHostedService with delegate to create the instance?
What am I not getting here?
I apologize for any misunderstanding as I'm fairly new to DI/IoC patterns. I'm migrating from legacy WCF to WebAPI/Grpc so I'm exploring various solutions here.

You were very close on your first attempt
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDeviceManagerService, DeviceManagerService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DeviceManagerService>());

Should be
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDeviceManagerService, DeviceManagerService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IDeviceManagerService>());

As you registered the DeviceManagerService type as IDeviceManagerService interface, you can only resolve the interface but not the specific type.

Yes! It's working. I'm using the Interface inside the API controller and everything works.
One last thing I don't understand. Should AddHostedService automatically register the Interface?
I mean, why is this method alone not working?
builder.Services.AddHostedService<IDeviceManagerService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DeviceManagerService>());
I mean.. AddHostedService is adding a Singleton after all

@Simon Because hosted services were invented to run background tasks. Not to initialize objects. You are actually "abusing" them to perform work that they were not designed for. I put "abusing" in quotes because hosted services are a simple but very powerful tool that allows you to do what you want but in a slightly different way. Check this answer to see how you can use them properly to initialize objects on startup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69700032/2557855

I am using hosted service to run a bg task, that is polling a device via serial port . The thing is, I have to read that value from an API controller, so the only way I found is to create a singleton implementation of IDeviceManagerService (that inherits from IHostedService) that exposes some methods to be called from my API Controller. Then I would register that instance to be accessible from the controller itself.
Basically,I'm creating the instance and using it in AddHostedService
Am I doing this wrong?
I apologise, but I'm fairly new to DI/IoC infrastructure.
Thank You
